# Receive POST data from ASP.NET code hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, http-post, http-get

Does anyone know the correct ASP.NET code to receive a image file POSTed from Objective-C? This file (for example image1.png) is to be saved into IIS server folder. Please take note that 'file control' is 'not' allowed on the iOS device. Asumming following objective-c code is used:

```
request = NSMutableUOLRequest requestwithURL:url;
assert[request != nil];
request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
request setHTTPBodyStream:self.consumerStream];

................
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just sending the image as the request stream. In that case, you could grab the [Request.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) and write it to a file:

```
ImagePOSTHandler : IHttpHandler {
    void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.jpg"))) {
           context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not using .NET 4, you'll need to manually copy the stream instead of using CopyTo.

Comment: Thanks Mark. May I know the code segment that you provide should appear in Page_Load() evenhandler of a default.aspx.cs file? And the url String for my objective-c code is http://localhost/myWesite/default.aspx

Comment: @cw - I would use a "Generic Web Handler" (ASHX) since you don't need the Page class - but it should work in an ASPX as well in Page_Load.